# Push Notification Windows Phone 8 Sample from MSDN

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I downloaded a sample from MSDN to send cloud notifications to Windows Phone 8.
But I am always getting channel URI as null ?
I am running it on Emulator 8.

Any Thoughts ??

```
public MainPage()
    {
        /// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
        HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

        // The name of our push channel.
        string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

        InitializeComponent();

        // Try to find the push channel.
        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

        // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

            // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            pushChannel.Open();

            // Bind this new channel for toast events.
            pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

        }
        else
        {
            // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.enter code here
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

        }
    }
```

> In the above code I am always getting channel Uri as "null"

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: please refer the above code

Answer (score 0):

It will always be null since you using emulator, try local machine.

Comment: I tried Using a Device too , still its coming as null , Can you please explain whats the issue in this. I have tried it in unlocked phone with internet access too .. When I run the app first time it doesnt crash when i run it second time it crashes as the channel URI is null

Comment: Maybe this will help http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/push-notification-channel-uri-null-57261.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have already tried that, no luck yet. Do we have to associate this app to store ? or de we need a certificate of some type to query the server ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with my network environment.
When I tried it on the non domain pc, It worked fine. Thanks for comments and time

Comment: Hello CodeR, can you please share the proper solution, I am also facing the same problem, I tried on WP8 Device (Nokia Lumia 520) but the channel uri always NULL. Infect my phone device have network connection as well as data connection.

Comment: Are you on a domain pc ?

Comment: Check firewall settings

Comment: @CodeR can you pls write steps it will help me a lot